# Stage.load(json) Issue..Kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, json, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a stage setup and I'm uploading some images over it that are draggable resizable and all..
Now I m using the stage.toJSON();
to save the state of the canvas..
and loading the json in another page..
using stage.load(json);

to load the stage..
and I just read that stage.toJSON(); is not able to save the state of the images...

any alternatives??
I'm trying to add few images inside the cavas and setting there position and resizing them....

I want to save the state of the images so that if I call the same json string again..I should be where I left off the canvas..

Thanks

Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 image.toJSON();
```

on your images separately to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/

You have to manually set the images using stage.get() since images aren't serializable.